# Can we MakeCurrent() two OpenGL contexts in more than one thread simultaneously?

Tags: winapi, opengl

Can we use `wglMakeCurrent()` function in more than one thread to use the same OpenGL context, simultaneously? or I have to create one OpenGL context per thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can we use wglMakeCurrent function in more than one thread to use the same opengl context, simultaneously?

No:

> [A rendering context can be current to only one thread at a time. You cannot make a rendering context current to multiple threads.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374387)

---

> I have to create one opengl context per thread?

Yes.